# Trying to delete outline on a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Toggle buttons and images on my site are getting a `dotted-outline` everytime I click on them. How do i remove the outline?
Basically I want a `outline:none` but I can't figure out the correct element in which I should apply it to.

(images [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmqPT.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEegt.png))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out just set

```
.elementor a{
  outline:none
}
``
```